# Empty 'current url' for Django deployed with Nginx and fastcgi

Tags: django, nginx, url-pattern

When I query this url

```
http://mywebsite.com/foos/
```

Django give me :

```
Page not found (404)
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://mywebsite.com/foos//    
The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

the errors :
 - in Request URL it add me '/' at the end,
 - in current URL is empty.

my spec :
I run my django website with nginx as reverseproxy to the fast_cgi.

Here my website conf for nginx :

```
server {
         listen   80;
         server_name  mywebsite.com;


             location / {
                     fastcgi_pass unix:/tmp/_var_wwwdjango_mywebsite.socket;
                     include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
             }
    }
```

here is my fastcgi_params file :

```
fastcgi_param   QUERY_STRING            $query_string;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_METHOD          $request_method;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_TYPE            $content_type;
fastcgi_param   CONTENT_LENGTH          $content_length;
fastcgi_param   PATH_INFO               $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_FILENAME         $request_filename;
fastcgi_param   SCRIPT_NAME             $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param   REQUEST_URI             $request_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_URI            $document_uri;
fastcgi_param   DOCUMENT_ROOT           $document_root;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PROTOCOL         $server_protocol;

fastcgi_param   GATEWAY_INTERFACE       CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_SOFTWARE         nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param   REMOTE_ADDR             $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param   REMOTE_PORT             $remote_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_ADDR             $server_addr;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_PORT             $server_port;
fastcgi_param   SERVER_NAME             $server_name;

#fastcgi_param  HTTPS                   $server_https;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param   REDIRECT_STATUS         200;
```

remark :

- if I add `url(r'^$', 'myapp.views.index')` to my pattern it render me the view for all my requests... so it's clearly a nginx conf or fast_cgi problem.
- When I execute my website with the django development server my url are ok.

Comment: Please can you update your question to include `/etc/nginx/fastcgi_params`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are missing the PATH_INFO parameter.

```
fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
```

See the nginx docs: http://wiki.nginx.org/DjangoFastCGI

If you try "nginx PATH_INFO django" in your favourite search engine, it looks like some users had to remove the SCRIPT_NAME parameter as well to get it to work.

Comment: Glad it worked. Did you have to remove SCRIPT_NAME, or was adding PATH_INFO enough?

Comment: I don't know the first time I didn't remove it and it wasn't work so I removed and I work ( I don't know because the fist time I forgot to restart nginx )so... If I think I will restest.