# Django urlpatterns not matching

Tags: python, django, url-pattern

I've been trying everything, but I can't get these numbers to match. Am I missing anything here? Like a non-default module?

```
    Page not found (404)
    Request Method: GET
    Request URL:    http://example.com/blog/1/1/1/
    Using the URLconf defined in blog.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:
    ^blog/(?P\d{4})/(?P\d{2})/(?P\d{2})/$
    ^blog/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/$
    The current URL, , didn't match any of these.
```

Also, my urls.py file:

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url                                                  
import views                                                                                         
from views import hello_world, date_try, blog_test                                                   

urlpatterns = patterns('',                                                                           
    url(r'^blog/(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/$', views.date_try),                 
    url(r'^blog/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/$', 'date_try'),                                                   
)
```

Comment: Is that your root urlconf, or is it being included by another urlconf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>I think `\d{4}` is only going to match exactly 4 digits.  Try `\d{1,4}`.</strike>

It looks like Django thinks your URL is empty.  How are you running Django?  Is [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298335/empty-current-url-for-django-deployed-with-nginx-and-fastcgi) useful?

Comment: `^blog/(\d+)/(\d+)/(\d+)/$` should  match `blog/1/1/1/`

Comment: Glad I can help!  If this did solve your problem, could you accept my answer? Accepting answers helps make [Stack Overflow better](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask).