# Django @login_required cause redirects loop when using nginx and fastcgi

Tags: python, django, nginx, fastcgi

I set LOGIN_URL like this in settings.py:

> ```
> LOGIN_URL = '/login/'
> ```

and in urls.py I and this URLConf:

> ```
> (r'^$', 'agent.index.redirect'),
> (r'^login/$', 'django.contrib.auth.views.login', {'template_name':'login.html'}),
> ```

and the agent.index.redirect view is like this:

> ```
> @login_required
> def redirect(request):
>     ...
> ```

and I run my Django site like this:

> ```
> python manage.py runfcgi host=127.0.0.1 port=8090 --settings=settings
> ```

the nginx.conf is like this:

> ```
> user nobody nobody;
> worker_processes  5;
> #error_log /var/log/nginx/error_log info;
>
> events {
>     worker_connections  1024;
>     use epoll;
> }
>
> http {
>     include         mime.types;
>     default_type    application/octet-stream;
>
>     log_format main
>         '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local] '
>         '"$request" $status $bytes_sent '
>         '"$http_referer" "$http_user_agent" '
>         '"$gzip_ratio"';
>
>     client_header_timeout   10m;
>     client_body_timeout     10m;
>     send_timeout            10m;
>
>     connection_pool_size            256;
>     client_header_buffer_size       1k;
>     large_client_header_buffers     4 2k;
>     request_pool_size               4k;
>
>     gzip on;
>     gzip_min_length 1100;
>     gzip_buffers    4 8k;
>     gzip_types      text/plain;
>
>     output_buffers  1 32k;
>     postpone_output 1460;
>
>     sendfile        on;
>     tcp_nopush      on;
>     tcp_nodelay     on;
>
>     keepalive_timeout       75 20;
>
>     ignore_invalid_headers  on;
>     index index.html;
>
>     server {
>         listen 80;
>         server_name localhost;
>         root /web/agent;
>
>         location /static  {
>             alias /web/agent/media;
>             access_log   off;
>             expires      30d;
>         }
>
>         location /media  {
>             alias /web/agent/admin_media;
>             access_log   off;
>             expires      30d;
>         }
>
>         location / {
>             # host and port to fastcgi server
>             fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:8090;
>             fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_script_name;
>             fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
>             fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
>             fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
>             fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
>             fastcgi_pass_header Authorization;
>             fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
>             fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
>             fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
>             fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
>             fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
>             fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;
>             fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
>             fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;
>             fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
>             fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
>             fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
>             fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
>             fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;
>             fastcgi_connect_timeout 30s;
>             fastcgi_send_timeout 30s;
>             fastcgi_read_timeout 30s;
>             fastcgi_buffer_size 128k;
>             fastcgi_buffers 8 128k;#8 128
>             fastcgi_busy_buffers_size 256k;
>             fastcgi_temp_file_write_size 256k;
>             fastcgi_intercept_errors on;
>         }
>         #access_log     /usr/local/nginx/logs/access_log main;
>         #error_log      /usr/local/nginx/logs/error_log;
>     }
> }
> ```

When I access [http://localhost], there's a redirect loop. And the access.log of nginx is like this:

> ```
> 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2013:18:13:51 +0800] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130220 Firefox/17.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2013:18:13:51 +0800] "GET /login/?next=// HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130220 Firefox/17.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2013:18:13:51 +0800] "GET /login/?next=/login//%3Fnext%3D// HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130220 Firefox/17.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2013:18:13:51 +0800] "GET /login/?next=/login//%3Fnext%3D/login//%253Fnext%253D// HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130220 Firefox/17.0"
> 127.0.0.1 - - [28/Feb/2013:18:13:51 +0800] "GET /login/?next=/login//%3Fnext%3D/login//%253Fnext%253D/login//%25253Fnext%25253D// HTTP/1.1" 302 5 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686; rv:17.0) Gecko/20130220 Firefox/17.0"
> ...and so on.
> ```

Can anyone help to solve this problem?

Comment: Your problem reminds me of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9298335/empty-current-url-for-django-deployed-with-nginx-and-fastcgi). Try removing `fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;`.

Comment: @Alasdair It works. Thanks a lot! But I don't know why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aha, the reason is:

> Django uses PATH_INFO to match against urlpatterns. Nginx’s fastcgi_params include doesn’t set that. It does set SCRIPT_NAME. If both PATH_INFO and SCRIPT_NAME are set to $fastcgi_script_name, Django seems to get an empty path for all requests. Just set PATH_INFO!

See more at http://aftnn.org/2009/jan/23/nginx-django-fastcgi/.

So solution is just removing this line:`fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;`
Thank @Alasdair very mach.

Answer (score 1):

This usually indicates that you have another URL pattern that matches the requested URL (probably all urls) and redirects to the login page. For example:

```
(r'^', 'agent.index.redirect'),
    ^ left out the end-of-string $
```

This would cause a redirect loop like you're experiencing. Do you have any other url patterns other than those listed in your question?

Comment: This problem only occurs when I use nginx and fastcgi. If run site using 
`python manage.py runserver`, there's no redirect loop.